# Ponyorm: filtering objects by multiple joined values in a JOIN

Tags: python, ponyorm

I am trying to implement a tag filtering mechanism where items can have an arbitrary number of tags associated with them, and I want to be able to find items which have any or all of the requested tags.

My schema is something like this:

```py
class Item(db.Entity):
    tags = orm.Set("ItemTag")

class ItemTag(db.Entity):
    item = orm.Required(Item)
    tag = orm.Required(str)
    orm.composite_key(item, tag)
    orm.composite_key(tag, item)
```

I am able to filter existing queries with a single tag easily:

```py
def filter_query_tag(query, tag:str):
    return orm.select(i for i in query for t in i.tags if t.key == tag)
```

and I am able to find items with *any* of the tags easily:

```py
def filter_query_any_tag(query, tags:typing.Union(set,list,tuple)):
    return orm.select(i for i in query for t in i.tags if t.key in tags)
```

but attempting to build a query that finds *all* of the tags throws an error:

```py
def filter_query_all_tags(query, tags:typing.Union(set,list,tuple)):
    for tag in tags:
        query = orm.select(i for i in query for t in i.tags if t.key == tag)
    return query
```

results in:

```
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5562, in select
    return make_query(args, frame_depth=cut_traceback_depth+1)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5558, in make_query
    return Query(code_key, tree.code, globals, locals, cells, left_join)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5717, in __init__
    translator = translator_cls(tree_copy, None, code_key, filter_num, extractors, vars, vartypes.copy(), left_join=left_join)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/sqltranslation.py", line 222, in __init__
    translator.init(tree, parent_translator, code_key, filter_num, extractors, vars, vartypes, left_join, optimize)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/sqltranslation.py", line 396, in init
    tableref = translator.sqlquery.add_tableref(name_path, parent_tableref, attr)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/sqltranslation.py", line 1211, in add_tableref
    assert name_path not in sqlquery.tablerefs
AssertionError
```

Presumably the issue is that it's having issues mapping multiple join names to the same table, which is possibly a bug in ponyorm. However, I suspect there is probably a better way to build the query without having to do multiple joins and filters in the first place.

I tried using `orm.left_join` instead of `orm.select`, like this:

```py
def filter_query_all_tags(query, tags:typing.Union(set,list,tuple)):
    for tag in tags:
        query = orm.left_join(i for i in query for t in i.tags if t.key == tag)
    return query
```

In this case I am able to filter on *two* tags simultaneously, but if I add a third tag I get:

```
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5566, in left_join
    return make_query(args, frame_depth=cut_traceback_depth+1, left_join=True)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5558, in make_query
    return Query(code_key, tree.code, globals, locals, cells, left_join)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5717, in __init__
    translator = translator_cls(tree_copy, None, code_key, filter_num, extractors, vars, vartypes.copy(), left_join=left_join)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/sqltranslation.py", line 222, in __init__
    translator.init(tree, parent_translator, code_key, filter_num, extractors, vars, vartypes, left_join, optimize)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/sqltranslation.py", line 343, in init
    names, try_extend_prev_query=not i)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/sqltranslation.py", line 598, in process_query_qual
    subquery_ast = prev_translator.construct_subquery_ast(prev_limit, prev_offset, aliases=aliases)
  File "/Users/fluffy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Publ-FUB3ZG92/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/sqltranslation.py", line 625, in construct_subquery_ast
    assert not star and len(aliases) == len(select_ast) - 1
AssertionError
```

Is there a primitive or idiomatic expression in ponyorm which allows me to specify that *all* values of a set must be present in the `ItemTag` values for any given `Item`?

Comment: AssertionError means you reach the unexpected behavior. Would you mind to open an issue for this case? https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/new

Comment: @sashaaero Opened https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/488, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```py
def filter_query_all_tags(query, tags:typing.Union(set,list,tuple)):
    for tag in tags:
        query = query.filter(lambda i: orm.exists(t for t in i.tags if t.key == tag))
    return query
```

However, this seems like it could possibly be better.